# CkEditor multiple values in templates property

Tags: templates, jquery-plugins, properties, ckeditor

How can I add more than one value to the 'templates' property of the CKEDITOR plugin?

```
CKEDITOR.replace('text', {
    templates: 'template_1'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer you have to use a ',' like:

```
    CKEDITOR.replace('text', {
       templates: 'template_1, template_2'
    });
```